# How do I reload a linked blender file?

Tags: blend-files, linked-data

How do I reload a linked blender file?

I linked a `.blend` file into another. After I update the linked file (say change the material color), how do I make the project I imported it into update?

Answer (score 41):

[image]

1. Navigate to *Outliner*
2. Change type to *Blender File*
3. Right click on the .blend you want to reload
4. Hit Reload

Then you can reload the lastly reloaded file by pressing <kbd>Space</kbd> and writing down *Reload Library*

[image]

Comment: Why to -1? This is built-in method how to reload a linked .blend file. It should work.

Comment: I voted up, actually that was the best answer in my case :)

Comment: This was the best for my workflow as well.

Comment: When I do this in Blender 2.9 the linked character just desappear in viewport after hit reload. and it is not Reload Library in search menu :(

Answer (score 7):

Try saving and reloading the file.

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> to save.
2. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>O</kbd> to open the recent files menu, then select the top entry or press <kbd>1</kbd>.

Answer (score 7):

There is also a great addon, written by *Pablo Vazquez*, called **"Amaranth"**, which include a little feature (among others) : *"Save and reload"*

http://www.pablovazquez.org/amaranth/ (see the bottom of this page)

After installing it, you'll just have to hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd> <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> <kbd>W</kbd> (or go into *File* menu), to save and reload the current file. It should update all linked data as well.

Answer (score 4):

Another great add-on that will allow you to easily edit your linked object from your scene and then switch back to your scene containing the linked item is called Edit Linked Library.

Edit Linked Library is simple to use and you can find usage instructions at http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Object/Edit_Linked_Library

Answer (score 3):

File - Revert - that's easy ;)

Comment: This works! Of course, if the current file has unsaved changes you want to keep, press ctrl+s to save first!