# Re-import updated CAD model into blender, retain existing surface materials and settings

Tags: rendering, import, append

Good day everyone.

I am an Architect who primarily works in Archicad, Revit and SketchUp. I recently started to learn my way around Blender as I would like to use it as an Architectural visualization tool.

I can export a building from Archicad just fine, import it into blender, apply materials, lights etc. just fine and render it.

The problem I'm running into is that whenever I have to make changes to the Archicad model I don't know how to go about re-importing the updated CAD file to blender without having to redo everything in blender ( materials, lights etc.)

Is there a way to do this in Blender similarly to programs like Lumion and Artlantis?

Regards, 
Hanrich

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/10709/re-import-obj-and-replace-existing/10715#10715

Comment: But by linking the .blend file with the updated geometry it would mean that I won't be able to edit the surfaces and materials.

Comment: Not directly, no, only through the source file