# obj to glTF batch exporter

Tags: python, scripting, export, gltf, obj

I have a set of obj exports comprising of a million files(each file between 100-200kb). Is there are a way to pick up files from a folder and export them to glTF? What I am talking about is batch importing obj files to batch export to glTF. I am new to blender and would really appreciate if anybody can guide me on this.

Comment: related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/168140/batch-exporting-scene-collections-or-selected-objects-using-gltf-blender-io/175968#175968

Answer (score 1):

You can do batch export from Blender in the same way as described in [Export multiple objects to .obj](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5382/export-multiple-objects-to-obj), but with the [glTF export API](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.export_scene.html#bpy.ops.export_scene.gltf). That said, I think a standalone CLI converter might be easier to use in this case, like [obj2gltf](https://github.com/CesiumGS/obj2gltf).

Comment: I have been referring to this link and trying to get the import>export and later delete it running it on loop https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/10709/re-import-obj-and-replace-existing?noredirect=1&lq=1