# Update an existing (animated) model

Tags: modeling, animation

I have one .blend project where I've imported objects via .dae files.
I've set up a scene and made animations etc...

Now there is a request to modify details of one or more object.

**Question 1:**
Is there a way that I can replace my existing model with a newer version where I keep the location, rotation, scale and animations?
Because now I need to delete the object, add it again and animate it again.

**Question 2:**
For future projects, how do you set up a blender project to overcome such problems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of ways. Two simple approaches (assuming you are talking about static meshes):

Switch the mesh in the Properties window - Object Data:

[image]
[image]

Or if you have LocRotScale keyframed, switch the action in the action editor:

[image]

Comment: thanks, works fine.
additional info: you first need to add or import the object that you want to use.

Answer (score 1):

You could convert the .dae file into separate .blend files and link (Menu: File/Link)  instead of append into master file. In the master file you create the animations or pose-libraries needed. If the rig doesn't change you would be able to edit the mesh and just refresh the linked files. (The first related link has a more detailed and illustrated answer).

Related:

- [Re-Import obj and replace existing](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/10709/re-import-obj-and-replace-existing)
- [How do I reload a linked blender file?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6302/how-do-i-reload-a-linked-blender-file)