# Is there a way to internally restart blender, or equivalent to closing and opening manually - even if it's just a temporary save and quit and reload

Tags: add-on, system

.. the addons get broken and addon reload doesn't even work, tried a bunch of stuff, closing and opening blender does it.. 
Any ideas on how to restart blender would be great..

Comment: See https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/6308/1245, however it will save the file first

Comment: It would help if you add information on what exactly you are having problems with. What addon is causing the issue and what bunch of stuff you have tried.