# Can i edit the textures of linked character?

Tags: animation, texturing

Which option should i choose or how can i edit the textures of character when edited in original file should see in linked file.

Comment: Hello :). You cannot directly edit linked files, but you can refresh them to see them updated. The fastest way is to save your file and then hit *File->Revert*. [This thread should help](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/6302/78972).

Comment: This should be possible through *Library Override*. I'll test it.

Comment: Might have misunderstood your question. You want to edit locally and see the changes saved in the linked file? Because that is not possible as far as I'm aware. Local changes through library overrides are possible though.